# Multi language support in my android app

Tags: java, android, node.js

I have an application that pulls information from a web server and displays it. I know that Android has some nice language features where you can put multiple strings.xml files inside the project for specific languages. Is there a way to convert the text from the server (which is in english) to whatever local the user has set on their device?

Comment: Please check the link https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/getting-started

Comment: this may help you:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/45351072/7612991 but you need to add string file by own, there is no translator which converts string files in multi-language

Answer (score 0):

You can only change locale for the text in Strings.xml

You cannot translate json data from server unless there is some translation API involved.