# Kotlin : Translate UI from English to French android

Tags: android, kotlin

In my android app with kotlin, I add a button in a slide menu that when I clickOn the language change from English to French.
I have two idea, The First One create two layout one mainactivity_en.xml and the second layout mainactivity.xml.
The Second idea, is to keep one layout mainactivity.xml, and doing test if language "Fr" I change all fields with french language else "En" with english.
I would like to know what's the more efficient and optimised solution to translate UI from English to Frensh ?

Answer (score 0):

Just set the locale and update resources programmatically.  A quick google comes up with a [walkthrough](https://devdeeds.com/android-change-language-at-runtime/).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to maintain two separate activities. The strings.xml is appropriate for this. Then you would have two values folders in your res directory. One for `values` and the other for `values_en` or `values_fr` depending on what language is the primary language. The [Localization Documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization) has more details. To update the language at runtime see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45351072/112263).